# Grant an IAM user access to one RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I have made a RDS instance and want to grant one of my user to access to that RDS instance. I'm wondering how I can give this permission.

I have granted RDSFULLACESS in attach policy of my IAM user then simulate it like this:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "rds:*",
            "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
            "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
            "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
            "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
            "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
            "sns:ListSubscriptions",
            "sns:ListTopics",
            "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
            "logs:GetLogEvents"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:accountIDofIAMUser:db:instancename"
    }
]
}
```

But my user still can not access to this RDS instance,what's the problem? he can make it himself but I don't want he makes another one!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the policy above has the correct ARN for the database and is attached to the IAM user then it will allow full management actions on the RDS database, things like stopping the database or restoring a backup.

To explictly exclude the "Create" permissions, based on the list on this page 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_rds.html
include all the permissions you do need, for example.  In this context "Deny" always beats "Allow".  "Create" permissions are ok vs. the already existing database but don't apply elsewhere.

```
    {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "rds:*",
            "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
            "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
            "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
            "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
            "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
            "sns:ListSubscriptions",
            "sns:ListTopics",
            "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
            "logs:GetLogEvents"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:accountIDofIAMUser:db:instancename"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "rds:Create*"
      ],
      "NotResource": [
         "arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:accountIDofIAMUser:db:instancename"
       ] 
    }
    ]
    }
```

I haven't tested this policy, it's just an example

If the user needs access to the database as a consumer of data then this is not managed in this way.  They need to have two things for this

# network access to the RDS instance via correct networking and correctly setup security groups

# user account credentials for the database

For mysql the process of initially connecting is described here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html

Comment: Yeah I want to give full access to only one RDS instance but that policy doesn't work, I don't want my user could make another RDS instance. do u have any idea ?

Comment: But my policies don't work. I'm setting this policy in the following link:   https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp?#users/username/AmazonRDSFullAccess                                                                    is it correct? Where should I put these policies?

Comment: https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home select policies, click create policy, add it and save under name.  Then go back to iam home, select users, click user to modify, permissions tab, "attach policy" and select the policy you have just made

Comment: @ Vorsprung thanks I made it but now in the console of my user it's not avalable: error:user/spsadmin is not authorized to perform: rds:DescribeDBInstances

Comment: that is correct behaviour see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeDBInstances.html

Answer (score 2):

Please find below policy for single user single rds start-stop access.

Create below policy and give rds arn in the resource section.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds:AddTagsToResource",
                "rds:ListTagsForResource",
                "rds:DescribeDBSnapshots",
                "rds:DescribeDBEngineVersions",
                "rds:DescribeDBParameters",
                "rds:DescribeDBParameterGroups",
                "rds:StopDBInstance",
                "rds:StartDBInstance"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:accountnumber:db:dbidentifier"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds:DescribeDBClusterSnapshots",
                "rds:DescribeDBInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Attach this policy to user whome you want to grant access.